# How to position html form in specific part of an image using css with all viewports supported?

Tags: html, css

I have the following image with a hand carrying an smartphone. I want to display html form inside the form part as shown in the image.[image]

How can i implement this using css ? Do i need to do viewport and image size calculations using js/jquery ?

I was only able to align the content to center.

my html:

```
<div id="box-search">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9vqPVU6.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
              <form action="/action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

my css code:

```
img {
    display: block;
}

.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the image like that and mantain its original dimension, you can set fixed positioning values in pixel.
Set these CSS properties for `.caption`:

```css
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px; /* some padding, and below the dimension properties */
  top: 247px;
  left: 205px;
  height: 257px;
  width: 419px;
}
```

Now if you are not going to use a fixed dimension, that is your image will mantain the proportions but will shrink on smaller screens, you can use percentage to position and scale the `.caption`.

```css
.caption {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  top: 34.5%;
  left: 17%;
  height: 35.5%;
  width: 35%;
}
```

In both ways, the caption element (containing the form) will be exactly positioned on the device screen of the image.